# If $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)$ , $\lim_{x\to a+}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to b-}f(x)$ exist then $f$ is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

It's quite intuitive if you draw the graph-- there are no asymptotes so it must be bounded-- but how do you prove it? proving there exists a maximum and a minimum? Using the extreme value theorem? But it's not a closed interval! Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: How about the Heine-Borel theorem?

Answer (score 3):

Define a new function:
$$
f^\star(x) = \begin{cases} \lim_{x \to a+} f(x) &\text{ if } x = a\\
f(x) &\text{ if } a < x < b\\
\lim_{x \to b-} f(x) &\text{ if } x = b
\end{cases}
$$ This new function *is defined* on the closed interval $[a, b]$ and it is continuous on $[a, b]$, **by construction**. So now you can use the extreme value theorem on $f^\star$ instead to conclude that $f^\star$ is bounded. Since $f$ is just $f^\star$ restricted to $(a, b)$, it is must also be bounded.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $f$ is not bounded, so there is a sequence of points $(x_n)$ so that $f(x_n)>n$ but $(x_n)\in [a,b]$ so there is a subsequence $(x_{n_j})$ that convergers on $[a,b]$ the limite point cannot belong to $(a,b)$ because $f$ is continuos on this interval. So the limit point is $=a$ or $=b$, without loss generality, suppose that $x_{n_j}\rightarrow a$ but by hypothesis the limit below exist
$$
\lim_{j}f(x_{n_j})
$$

but by constructer $\lim_jf(x_{n_j})=\infty$ an contradiction.

Comment: Hmmmm I've just started calculus...is there a more elementary way? Thanks anyway for your help!

Comment: You can use that $f$ is bounded on intervals $(a,a+\epsilon)$ and $(b-\epsilon,b)$, just use definitnion of existence of this limits, and that $f|_{[a+\epsilon,b-\epsilon]}$ it's also bounded because $f$ is continuous and $[a+\epsilon,b-\epsilon]$ is compact, a continuos function on compact is always bounded (it's a theorem).